# azure -command not found while running GET command

Tags: azure, curl, get

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer<token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2019-03-21T00:00:00Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-03-24T20:40:00Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'name'&$select=operationName,status,level
```

This command is used for collection azure activity log I am running this command in the CLI its giving error
bash: =,status,level: command not found...
bash: =eventTimestamp: command not found...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution myself

the POST request that you are using copy and paste to Postman(software). Then click on "code". `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp%20ge%20%272019-03-21T00:00:00Z%27%20and%20eventTimestamp%20le%20%272019-03-24T20:40:00Z%27%20and%20resourceGroupName%20eq%20%27Ajay%27&$select=operationName,status,level'`

Comment: %20 = space  and %27= '